# Php STR_REPLACE not work with double quote

Tags: php, str-replace

Can someone help me, i need transform string as :
Here is the HTML code :

```
<p><img src="/images/blog//023.jpg" alt="sposi a venezia" width="910" height="620" data-src="salvatorefranco.com/images/blog//023.jpg"; /><img src="/images/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" alt="sposi a venezia" width="910" height="620" data-src="salvatorefranco.com/images/blog//…; /></p>


alt=""   to 
alt="title image"
```

I tried :

```
$var = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$title_image.'"', $object);
```

but not work...
thanks
Salvatore

Comment: can you show us the content of $object?

Comment: <p><img src="/images/blog/023.jpg" alt="" width="910" height="620" data-src="/images/blog/023.jpg" /><img src="/images/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" alt="" width="910" height="620" data-src="images/blog/wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" /></p>

Comment: I dont't know how insert corretly code...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$object='alt=""';
$title_image="test";
$var = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$title_image.'"', $object); 
echo $var;
```

Comment: Yes this work, but I receive $object from $POST, and in echo working, but when write database, not write correctly...

Comment: var $object receive with 

$object = ($_POST[object']); 
$object='alt=""';
$title_image="test";
$var = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$title_image.'"', $object);

and when write database, not see that alt change

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work correctly.

```
<?php

$object = '<p><img src="/images/blog/023.jpg" alt="" width="910" height="620" data-src="/images/blog/023.jpg" /><img src="/images/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" alt="" width="910" height="620" data-src="/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" /></p>';

$title_image = "title image";

echo $var = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$title_image.'"', $object);
```

?>

> Output

`<p><img src="/images/blog/023.jpg" alt="title image" width="910" height="620" data-src="/images/blog/023.jpg" /><img src="/images/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" alt="title image" width="910" height="620" data-src="/blog//wedding-photographer-in-portofino.jpg" /></p>`

[Working Link](https://eval.in/825035)

Answer (score 0):

We can try str_replace function to solve this problem

```
 $alt='alt=""' ;
 $var = str_replace("{$alt}", 'alt="title image"',"{$alt}"); 
 echo $var;
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)